# Programmatically toggle a jquery treeview item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview

I have a jquery treeview as navigation for a website. I am using the options:

```
unique:true,
collapsed:true
```

but I need to have the first item expanded. I also would like to be able to toggle states in certain functions.

How can i programmatically toggle a jquery treeview item?

I have read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview) and searched everywhere, but I can't figure it out. My javascript/jquery skills are not great, so I can't figure out how to add this feature myself.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

#### Update:

I spent so long looking at the options/source code I didn't see the "closed" class right there in the intro page. That helps a lot!

also, I found that using (pointed in the right direction by Chris Gutierrez):

```
$('#tree div.expandable-hitarea:first').click();
```

works to expand that item! Now, I just have to create my own toggle functions.

Thanks.

Comment: "I also would like to be able to toggle states in certain functions." Can you give us more details? Perhaps posting your code will make perfect sense.

Comment: Post code if you really want help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could just execute a click on the desired li. For the first one try something like

```
$("#example li.collapsable:first").click();
```

Or when you initially render the html, just add the "expandable" class to the first li.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, but it did help me figure it out (I've updated my question)

Comment: The css selector I used in the answer was setup for the example in the documentation. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

The demo at the documentation link you provided, does exactly that. The source is available. Is there a problem with the way they do it there?